# Python pandas - filter rows after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, filter, lambda, group-by

For example, I have the following table:

```
index,A,B
0,0,0
1,0,8
2,0,8
3,1,5
4,1,3
```

After grouping by `A`:

```
0:
index,A,B
0,0,0
1,0,8
2,0,8

1:
index,A,B
3,1,5
4,1,3
```

What I need is to drop rows from each group, where the number in column `B` is less than maximum value from all rows from group's column `B`. Well I have a problem translating and formulating this problem to English so here is the example:

Maximum value from rows in column `B` in group `0`: **8**

So I want to drop row with index `0` and keep rows with indexes `1` and `2`

Maximum value from rows in column `B` in group `1`: **5**

So I want to drop row with index `4` and keep row with index `3`

I have tried to use pandas filter function, but the problem is that it is operating on all rows in group at one time:

```
data = <example table>
grouped = data.groupby("A")
filtered = grouped.filter(lambda x: x["B"] == x["B"].max())
```

**So what I ideally need is some filter, which iterates through all rows in group.**

Thanks for help!

P.S. Is there also way to only delete rows in groups and do not return `DataFrame` object?

Comment: the last bit is totally ambiguous: if you're deleting rows in each group, but *not* returning a dataframe, then what do you want to return?

Comment: Your data, when comparing the full table to the groups, don't match. please clear this up.

Comment: Sorry I was a little bit busy when writting this question. Data are correct now. Well I mean just to delete rows from groups and keep these groups as they are - I need to apply several filters and after each apply is needed new groupby.

Comment: `df.query` and `pd.eval` seem like good fits for this use case. For information on the `pd.eval()` family of functions, their features and use cases, please visit [Dynamic Expression Evaluation in pandas using pd.eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval).

Comment: how do I apply the filter back to a groupby results.  Do I have to convert the groupby results to a dataframe then apply the filter?  I want to create a "having" affect.  dfg=df2[(df2['AcctType']=='E')].groupby('CoaDescription')['TotalExpense'].sum()
filter=dfg.apply(lambda g: g >10000)
dfg=dfg[filter]
ax=sns.barplot(y=dfg.index,x=dfg)
plt.show()

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You just need to use `apply` on the `groupby` object. I modified your example data to make this a little more clear:

```
import pandas
from io import StringIO

csv = StringIO("""index,A,B
0,1,0.0
1,1,3.0
2,1,6.0
3,2,0.0
4,2,5.0
5,2,7.0""")

df = pandas.read_csv(csv, index_col='index')
groups = df.groupby(by=['A'])
print(groups.apply(lambda g: g[g['B'] == g['B'].max()]))
```

Which prints:

```
         A  B
A index      
1 2      1  6
2 4      2  7
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. Can I just ask you, what does `apply()` specifically do? And I am a little bit confused with `g[g['B']`

Comment: @jirinovo `groupby.apply(function)` runs every single group through that function and concatenates all of the results.  `g[...]` is fancy/boolean indexing -- meaning that it only returns rows where that inner condition is true. In this case, the condition is `g['B'] == g['B'].max()`, e.g., all the rows where the value in column B is equal to the largest value of B within that group.

Comment: Thanks. I personally find it misleading that the `filter` function doesn't filter rows based on some criterion. It feels like the obvious behavior.

Answer (score 34):

EDIT: I just learned a much neater way to do this using the `.transform` group by method:

```
def get_max_rows(df):
    B_maxes = df.groupby('A').B.transform(max)
    return df[df.B == B_maxes]
```

`B_maxes` is a series which identically indexed as the original `df` containing the maximum value of `B` for each `A` group.  You can pass lots of functions to the transform method. I think once they have output either as a scalar or vector of the same length. You can even pass some strings as common function names like `'median'`. 
This is slightly different to Paul H's method in that 'A' won't be an index in the result, but you can easily set that after.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df_lots_groups = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(30000, 3), columns = list('BCD')
df_lots_groups['A'] = np.random.choice(range(10000), 30000)

%timeit get_max_rows(df_lots_groups)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.86 ms per loop

%timeit df_lots_groups.groupby('A').apply(lambda df: df[ df.B == df.B.max()])
1 loops, best of 3: 5.83 s per loop
```

EDIT:

Here's a abstraction which allows you to select rows from groups using any valid comparison operator and any valid groupby method:

```
def get_group_rows(df, group_col, condition_col, func=max, comparison='=='):
    g = df.groupby(group_col)[condition_col]
    condition_limit = g.transform(func)
    df.query('condition_col {} @condition_limit'.format(comparison))
```

So, for example, if you want all rows in above the median B-value in each A-group you call

```
get_group_rows(df, 'A', 'B', 'median', '>')
```

A few examples:

```
%timeit get_group_rows(df_lots_small_groups, 'A', 'B', 'max', '==')
100 loops, best of 3: 2.84 ms per loop
%timeit get_group_rows(df_lots_small_groups, 'A', 'B', 'mean', '!=')
100 loops, best of 3: 2.97 ms per loop
```

Comment: I had to cut down on coffee because of how the pandas documentation made my blood pressure shoot up... May I ask where you learned about this thing? Also, allow me to [link to the `transform()` doc page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform)

Comment: I love Pandas but the docs, error messages and testing leave something to be desired. I don't remember where I first saw `transform` in use but I'm pretty sure it was here on SO. I often find novel ways of solving problems by looking at questions & answers here. If you use `ipython notebook` you can use tab completion to scan through the various methods, read the docstrings (not great, I know) and just experiment with them (in this case create a group by object and scan its methods)

Comment: @mccc you need to look at the human-written docs and not the auto-generated references: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation

Comment: Would this also work without an aggregation function like max, mean, ...? So for example, if I only want to return the rows of groups where 'some_column == 1'?

Comment: This is really great; any idea how we can apply multiple filter conditions to this?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by multiple conditions. My naive answer is that you would generate a Boolean vector for each and chain them with `&`. Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 12):

Here's the other example for : **Filtering the rows with maximum value after groupby operation using idxmax() and .loc()**

```
In [465]: import pandas as pd

In [466]:   df = pd.DataFrame({
               'sp' : ['MM1', 'MM1', 'MM1', 'MM2', 'MM2', 'MM2'],
               'mt' : ['S1', 'S1', 'S3', 'S3', 'S4', 'S4'], 
               'value' : [3,2,5,8,10,1]     
                })

In [467]: df
Out[467]: 
   mt   sp  value
0  S1  MM1      3
1  S1  MM1      2
2  S3  MM1      5
3  S3  MM2      8
4  S4  MM2     10
5  S4  MM2      1

### Here, idxmax() finds the indices of the rows with max value within groups,
### and .loc() filters the rows using those indices :
In [468]: df.loc[df.groupby(["mt"])["value"].idxmax()]                                                                                                                           
Out[468]: 
   mt   sp  value
0  S1  MM1      3
3  S3  MM2      8
4  S4  MM2     10
```

Answer (score 4):

All of these answers are good but I wanted the following:

```
(DataframeGroupby object) --> filter some rows out --> (DataframeGroupby object)
```

Shrug, it appears that is harder and more interesting than I expected. So this one liner accomplishes what I wanted but it's probably not the most efficient way :)

```
gdf.apply(lambda g: g[g['team'] == 'A']).reset_index(drop=True).groupby(gdf.grouper.names)
```

Working Code Example:

```
import pandas as pd

def print_groups(gdf): 
    for name, g in gdf: 
        print('\n'+name) 
        print(g)

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['sue', 'jim', 'ted', 'moe'],
                   'team': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 
                   'fav_food': ['tacos', 'steak', 'tacos', 'steak']})                               

gdf = df.groupby('fav_food')                                                                                                                                           
print_groups(gdf)                                                                                                                                                      

    steak
        name team fav_food
    1  jim    A    steak
    3  moe    B    steak

    tacos
        name team fav_food
    0  sue    A    tacos
    2  ted    B    tacos

fgdf = gdf.apply(lambda g: g[g['team'] == 'A']).reset_index(drop=True).groupby(gdf.grouper.names)                                                                      
print_groups(fgdf)                                                                                                                                                     

    steak
      name team fav_food
    0  jim    A    steak

    tacos
      name team fav_food
    1  sue    A    tacos
```

Comment: Is there any  reason why everyone hates semantic names for variables when you  write code in Python? What's the meaning of  ```g```.  What's the  meaning of  ```fgdf``` ?

Comment: @bibscy `g` is for grouped (I think). Usually `grouped` is used though. `df` is widely used as `dataframe`. `fgdf` = `final grouped dataframe` ( I presume)