# Pandas groupby and agg by condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

```
df.groupby(['Month']).agg({'Status' : ['count']})
```

The line above groups the dataframe by `Month` and counts the number of `Status` for each month. Is there a way to only get a count where `Status=X`? Something like the incorrect code below:

```
df.groupby(['Month']).agg({'Status' == 'X' : ['count']})
```

Essentially, I want a count of how many `Status` are `X` for each month.

Comment: Please add some sample data in text format  for us to to check

Comment: Have you tried `.filter` method. I can't comment much without the sample data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27488080/python-pandas-filter-rows-after-groupby , have you checked this link. It explains how to use `.apply` to do what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A short way

```
(df.Status == 'X').groupby(df.Month).sum()
```

A long way

```
df.where(df.Status == 'X').groupby('Month').Status.count()
```

Answer (score 7):

Let us do something different

```
pd.crosstab(df.Month,df.Status)['X']
```

Comment: me to! @Andy L.

Comment: @ansev: I like Wen's different things. He usually comes up with surprisingly refreshed solution which I never think of. I still remember his solution using `sum` to `concatenate` series of lists which I never thought of before :)

Answer (score 7):

Also can use **lambda function**

```
df.groupby('Month').agg(lambda x: (x=='X').sum())
```

or

```
df.groupby('Month').Status.agg(lambda x: (x=='X').sum())
```

Answer (score 1):

You an do `df.loc[df.Status=='X'].groupby(['Month']).agg({'Status' : ['count']})`