# Pandas Apply Function - Syntax for row filtering

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, apply

Similar to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27488080/python-pandas-filter-rows-after-groupby), I need to use the apply function to some data after using groupBy.

Suppose we have the following dataset with column heads A,B,C:

```
 a 0 2
 b 0 3
 c 0 4
 a 1 1
 b 1 2
 c 1 5
 a 0 3
 b 1 2
 c 0 1
```

and the following group by is applied:

```
   mydf=df.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].max()
```

I need to filter the group by result by a filter to show only those where C is 3, but get an error.

```
       print(mydf.apply(lambda g: g[g['C'] == 3]))
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with a `lambda` here:

```
df.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].max().loc[lambda x: x==3]
```

---

```
A  B
a  0    3
b  0    3
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thank you, I accepted the answer. If you don't mind, could you also tell me how to apply the same filter on either A or B, after performing the group function?

Comment: @Fabiana you can reset the index and use loc example: `df.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].max().reset_index().loc[lambda x:x['A']=='a']` which will filter column A equal to a for the grouped value